# Can a function that is not by definition a function have an "inverse"?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

The function f: N -> N, where f(n) = n - 2 I know is not a function (since 0 maps to -2 and -2 is not an element of the Naturals).

Is it possible for the inverse (let's say g) of f to be g : N -> N, g(n) = n + 2 (g is by definition a function) or is there no inverse because f is not by definition a function?

Thanks

Comment: It's more correct to say that $g$ is a function that doesn't have a (two-sided) inverse.

Comment: Agreed. There is such a thing as a "one-sided inverse".

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really correct to say that $f$ is not a function. It's a function, just not from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$. Writing "let $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be defined by $f(x)=n-2$" seems to me a bit like writing "Let $k$ be the even number $3$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define $f$: $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$, it is not bijective, so we can't speak about its inverse.

but if you define $f$: $\mathbb N\setminus{\{0,1\}} \to \mathbb N$, then it is a bijection and its inverse function is given by

$g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\setminus{\{0,1\}}$

$\;\;\;n\mapsto n+2$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you